# Setting width of text mentioned inside printf

Tags: c, width, printf

I have some code in some legacy debug files which has printf statements like this:

```
printf ("Abc1 = %d\n", var1);
printf ("Mnop2 = %d\n", var2);
```

This file has some 100 printf statements like this. The text (eg. Abc1) length varies between all these statements and the output of this looks pretty ugly.

My question is can I somehow mention the length of the text field which is mentioned inside ("") ?
I know we can add a %s and move the text outside. I dont want to do this as this is a legacy code and also, there are 100 or more printfs which I need to change.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Do you mean you want the numbers to start on the same column?

Comment: @theunamedguy: yes, I want something like Abc1   = 123

Comment: Then my answer should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to sneak in the tidy output behind the scenes without "intruding" on the existing code.

First, replace `printf` with a custom name. Then you can write a wrapper around it. If your compiler understands variadic macros, this may just be a macro. Otherwise you can roll your own `printf`-like function with variadic arguments and `vprintf`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#if VAR_ARG_MACRO_AVAILABLE

    #define tprintf(fmt, ...) do {          \
        printf("%.*s", 24 - strlen(fmt),    \
            "                        ");    \
        printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__);           \
    } while (0)

#else

#include <stdarg.h>

int tprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    int n;

    va_start(va, fmt);

    n = 24 - strlen(fmt);
    if (n < 0) n = 0;
    printf("%.*s", n, "                        ");

    n += vprintf(fmt, va);

    va_end(va);

    return n;
}

#endif

int main()
{
    tprintf("a = %d\n", 2);
    tprintf("alpha = %d\n", 21);
    tprintf("alphabetical = %d\n", 112);

    return 0;
}
```

The macro solution relies on variable names of less than about twenty characters. Otherwise, the absolute value of the field width will be taken, which may mangle your layout.

Using `strlen` (and not, for example, `strchr(fmt, '=')`), is an approximation and will not work if you have format specifiers of different lengths, e.g. `%zu`, `%llu` and so on.

Comment: Tried the macro part, and its working as expected. Thank you for the simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

For left-aligning:

```
int NumSpacesNeeded=32-strlen("Abc1 = ");
char buf[32];
memset(buf, 0, 32);
memset(buf, ' ', numSpacesNeeded);
printf("Abc1 = %s %d\n", buf, var1);
```

This might be a lot of work, though.

Comment: Thanks theunnamedguy. But, can I bring '=' also along with the number ?

Comment: Just place the tab in front of the '='

Comment: The tab character will look just as ugly (or arguably uglier) if the numbers exceed your tab width.

Comment: You can use multiple tabs if need be

Comment: @theunnamedguy: I tried this. But, based on the length of the text before, the = %d value goes out of alignment. i.e if the text width is more than one tab space, the value their moves it to the next tab which makes it unaligned

Comment: How do you know how many tabs you need then without looking at the number?

Comment: @MOehm: true. I tried that earlier, and same result. It still looks unaligned and ugly

Comment: @theunnamedguy : Yes, left aligned

Comment: @theunamedguy - in your current edit (#2), you haven't null-terminated the string of blanks and forgot to include `buf` in the `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, if you can either:

1. Add padding via your variable by using `%10d` where 10 is the amount spaces to pad.
2. Add spaces after your 'text' with `\t`, but you'll have to tweak how many \t you use if your texts differ a lot in length.

Comment: Tried \t. The text width varies between one to 3 tabs. So, the output doesnt get aligned. For me to use padding, I will have to manually edit like 100s of lines ... I am just trying to see if there is a simple solution ...

Comment: Oh, hmm, search and replace using "= %d\n" as your search string?

Comment: @nitekrawler: Sorry. I was thinking you were talking about padding the text, and moving text outside "". Yes, I can padd the number, but I would like to align even the = sign.

Comment: I see, I think @theunamedguy latest solution might be the best way to pad the text.

Answer (score 1):

Editing re-output the output by using a redirect.

sample for windows follow this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OUTFILE "temp.txt"

#define START stream = freopen(OUTFILE, "w", stdout)
#define END reOUT()


FILE *stream;

void reOUT(void){
    stream = freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
    FILE *fin = fopen(OUTFILE, "r");
    char line[128], field1[16], field2[16];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin)){
        if(sscanf(line, "%15s = %15s", field1, field2)==2)
            printf("%10s = %10s\n", field1, field2);
        else
            printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(fin);
    remove(OUTFILE);
}

int main(){
    int var1 = 11, var2=22;
    START;
    printf ("Abc1 = %d\n", var1);
    printf ("normal print\n");
    printf ("Mnop2 = %d\n", var2);
    END;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "/dev/tty" instead of "CON" for linux (i don't test). or use dup and dup2.